# How to get sum of numbers having exactly 2 one's in their binary representation in a range?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to find out the sum of numbers in a range say N which has exactly 2 ones in its binary representation.I wrote the code as:

```
N = int(raw_input())
sum1 = 0
for i in range(1, N + 1):
    if bin(i)[2:].count('1') == 2:
       sum1 = sum1 + i
```

This code takes a lot of time. Is there any faster way to do this calculation?

Comment: Can you assume that N = 2**M for some M? If so this is a simple combinatoric question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
def two_bit_numbers(N):
    bit0 = 0
    bit1 = 1
    while True:
        n = (1<<bit1) + (1<<bit0)
        if n > N:
            break
        yield n
        bit0 += 1
        if bit0 == bit1:
            bit1 += 1
            bit0 = 0

N = 100
sum1 = 0

for i in two_bit_numbers(N):
    # print i, bin(i)
    sum1 += i

print sum1
```

Comment: That was really efficient.

Answer (score -1):

If we look at how to find number that have two '1' when written in binary, we get to two cases :

- We have an element > 1 with 1 '1' in binary representation and we add 1 to it
- We have an element that has two '1' in binary representation, and we multiply it by 2.

So, to look for the number of element matching this case, you could just do :

```
num = int(raw_input())
def get_numbers(N):
    sum1 = []
    sum2 = []
    i = 2
    while i < N:
        # we add the elements of case 2
        sum1.extend(sum2)
        # we add the element of case 1
        sum1.append(i+1)
        sum2 = [2*x for x in sum1 if x > i]
        # we check for the elements with one more number when written in binary
        i *= 2
    # sum1 now contains all elements with two '1' in binary between 0 and the power of 2 above N.
    # we remove the elements above N
    sum1 = [x for x in sum1 if x <= N]
    # we sort the list
    sum1.sort()
    # we take the length of the list, of the number of elements with two '1' in binary between 0 and N
    return sum1

 print(get_numbers(num))
```

This should be faster, as we do not test every number between 0 and N, and have a log2(N) complexity.

Do not hesitate if you have any question about my method.

This method is slower than the one in the other answer (around 2 times slower)